# SQL query does not show the correct kilos, I don't know where is the problem

Tags: sql

This is my SQL query in text format:

```
SELECT sum(D.Kilogramos) as Kilogramos, C.Categoria , C.Tipo S Tipo, LA.Huerta,TC.TipoCorte, LA.JefeAcopio,LA.IdLote 
FROM dbo.MOV_EmpaqueDetalle D 
INNER JOIN dbo.Rep_Lote LA on LA.IdLote= D.IdLote 
INNER JOIN dbo.MOV_OrdenesCorte MO on MO.IdOrdenCorte = LA.IdOrdenCorte 
INNER JOIN dbo.PRO_Productos P on P.IdProducto=D.IdProducto 
INNER JOIN dbo.PRO_Categorias C ON C.IdCategoria=P.IdCategoria 
INNER JOIN dbo.MOV_Acuerdos A on A.IdAcuerdo=LA.IdAcuerdo 
INNER JOIN dbo.MOV_TiposCorte TC on A.IdTipoCorte=TC.IdTipoCorte 
WHERE CAST(MO.Fecha AS DATE) BETWEEN '2018-10-23' AND '2018-10-23' 
GROUP BY LA.Huerta, LA.IdLote,C.Categoria, C.Tipo, TC.TipoCorte, LA.JefeAcopio,Mo.Fecha 
ORDER BY LA.Huerta
```

The rows in the column `kilogramos` of the Huerta EL DOS are wrong, the information correct must be the  following:

```
Kilogramos    Huerta
13807.00      El DOS
```

I have got the accumulated row in sum function, the kilograms are wrong.

[image]

Comment: I added the text format of your SQL query to your question.

Comment: It's hard to answer a question like this without a [mcve]. Here is [a post with good tips](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for how to do that with an SQL question. Credit to zx485 for doing this for you, but for future reference, don't add important information in the comments: [edit] your question. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Answer (score -1):

Its kind of hard to provide an answer with the few information you provided, but I would suggest to check whether your `GROUP BY` is correct.

If you really just need the sum `Kilogramos` over the different `Huertas` your group condition should look like this: `GROUP BY LA.Huerta`

Comment: I continue having the same problem

Comment: Then you really should provide a better description of your problem. Maybe you could build an example using [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com). With a proper example its more likely that we could help you. Maybe you even solve your problem all by yourself by trying to provide a proper example.